# Ember JS Getting Started - Screen Flicker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ember.js, ember-cli, single-page-application

I'm currently going through the [getting started](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/getting-started/quick-start/) guide of Ember 2.13.

I've gotten up to the step of adding my first route: the `/scientists` route. I'm concerned because when I go to that URL, the screen flickers, something I didn't expect should be happening at all with such a basic SPA.

I've added a link [here](https://v.usetapes.com/Rus3M2KGfG), showcasing the flickering when changing the URLs.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about repainting in Chrome? Because in Safari it seems to work fine. But I tend to believe that this is because of some Safari optimization rather than Ember doing it's job in Safari and not Chrome.

I'm using the `ember serve` command. It also said that `watchman` was not installed but since that's just for discovering file changes, I figured it wouldn't impact this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it is flickering is because if you change the URL manually and hit enter, you are causing the page to reload (which causes the Ember app to reinitialize). To transition seamlessly between routes (without a flicker/page reload), you need to use Ember's [`{{link-to}}`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/templates/links/) helper. The [`{{link-to}}`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/templates/links/) helper doesn't cause a page reload and just transitions to the new route, unlike changing the URL manually.

There's also other methods of doing so when in the `controller` or `router` context. Chiefly, `Route#transitionTo` and `Controller#transitionToRoute`.

You should always use one of the aforementioned methods when routing within an Ember app. Make sure you don't use `<a>` tags or changing the `window.location`. Those methods will work, but it will cause that noticable flicker as it refetches and initializes the Ember app.

Indeed, `watchman` is an optional upgrade to improve the time it takes/the reliability of detecting file changes. It shouldn't affect the flicker you are describing.

Comment: Thank you quite a lot for the helpful response. Much appreciated.